# _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions SIGSEGV error while running production flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, crash

Everything was working fine until one day I decide to go back to an old commit and repair some features. After doing this, the project will just close after reaching the home screen.

App flow: Login -> HomeScreen -> all other things...
The app will log in and when the navigator pushes the home screen, it crashes. This only happens on the release app, not on any other flavors. But even tho the app crashes the flutter session is still connected if I used the flutter run --release command!

Sentry log: https://sentry.io/share/issue/8ca8511b20c747afaa60e185f0775637/

This is the code that does login and push to home screen:

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: isLoggedIn(prefs),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.data!["isLoggedIn"]) {
                    if (snapshot.data!["feedBackFormFound"])
                      return FeedbackForm();
                    if (snapshot.data!["loginError"]) return Credentials();

                    return RestartWidget(child: HomePage());
                  }

                  return Credentials();
                }

                return Center(
                    child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/log_in.json"),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Logging In...",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ));
              })
```

isLoggedIn():

```
Future<Map> isLoggedIn(SharedPreferences prefs) async {
Duration lastLogin = DateTime.parse(
        prefs.getString("lastLogin") ?? DateTime.now().toString())
    .difference(DateTime.now());

if (lastLogin.inMinutes < 30 && Scraper.cache["home"] != null) {
  return {
    "isLoggedIn": true,
    "loginData": Scraper.cache["home"],
    "feedBackFormFound":
        Scraper.cache["home"].contains("feedback form found"),
    "loginError": false,
  };
}

String loginData = await login();
await scraper.login();

if (!loginData.contains("Login error"))
  prefs.setString("lastLogin", DateTime.now().toString());

return {
  "isLoggedIn": loginData.length > 0,
  "loginData": loginData,
  "feedBackFormFound": loginData.contains("feedback form found"),
  "loginError": loginData.contains("Login error"),
};
```

}

I tried to go back in commits and tried again and still it crashes.
Project: https://github.com/hiruthicShaSS/eduserveMinimal

Device info:

1. OnePlus Android 11
2. Arch: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, armeabi
3. Kernel version: 4.14.190-perf+